# One word in describing a person who always trying to be creative

Tags: single-word-requests

Already ask Mr. Google obviously, and by far all the answer I found does not satisfy me. *Elysian , ingenious, innovative.*

I was actually searching for a tagline for an upcoming event, engineering stuff. ; A sudden wonder that I come across. "Trying his best to be creative and innovative." More likely an act of trying.

It's just my thought. I'm sorry for being insatiable about it. I wish you guys can help me.

Comment: Maybe a "wonderer" ?  At Walt Disney company, in their hey-day of breaking new ground in enterainment types,  they called their workers "Imagineers" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walt_Disney_Imagineering

Comment: Although I can't think of an ideal word rightaway, you have asked a very nice question!

Comment: Overeager? You try too hard, you get junk.

Comment: Much help, overeager seems right only the word does not bring the word creative. @WayfaringStranger

_Imagineers_ hahaha nicely put disney

Again, thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Demiurgic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demiurge)***

This word describes one who is a powerful creative force. Or perhaps you would consider:

***[Promethean](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Promethean)***

which indicates daring creativity or originality.

Comment: Very creative using term of God in words. Thank you!